# DatePicker and TimePicker change value

Tags: android, datepicker, timepicker, onactivityresult

[image]

I have DatePicker. If i change value(year) by using keyboard this value remains unchanged. Only when i click on Button "+" or "-" value changes....
Its my listener:

```
   datePicker.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            mDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            mDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            getArguments().putSerializable(EXTRA_DATE, mDate);
        }
    });
```

and similar problem with TimePicker(change anything)

```
      timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            mTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            getArguments().putSerializable(EXTRA_TIME, mTime);
        }

    })
```

and inside fragment

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_DATE){
        Calendar date = (Calendar)data.getSerializableExtra(DateFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
        mObject.setDate(date);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE, dd.MM.yy", Locale.US);
        mDateButton.setText(dateFormat.format(mObject.getDate().getTime()));
    }
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_TIME){
        Calendar date = (Calendar)data.getSerializableExtra(TimeFragment.EXTRA_TIME);
        mObject.setDate(date);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm, a", Locale.US);
        mTimeButton.setText(dateFormat.format(mObject.getDate().getTime()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DatePicker` respond with date change only after losing focus from it's year `EditText`.

So you can clear it's focus with `datePicker.clearChildFocus(getCurrentFocus())` and then get it's date values.

Comment: You are using it inside dialog?

Comment: Before closing this fragment, on `OK/Submit` button press
In fragment you can use `getView().getFocusedChild()` to find focused element

Comment: getFocusedChild() is missing

Comment: `((ViewGroup)getView()).getFocusedChild()` try

Comment: or.. you can even do : `datePicker.clearChildFocus(datePicker.getFocusedChild())`